TYPO3: use Powermail Signal in custom extension
TYPO3 10, Powermail 8.4
After successful double opt-in validation via Powermail, I want to send the mail data to an external API.
In \In2code\Powermail\Controller\FormController there is a signal AfterPersist what I could use.
In my extension I added in ext_localconf.php:
$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher::class);
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    \In2code\Powermail\Controller\FormController::class,
    'AfterPersist',
    \MyVendor\MyForms\EventListener\SendToApi::class,
    'run'
);

My class looks like this, for the moment:
namespace MyVendor\MyForms\EventListener;
    
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage;
    
class SendToApi {
    
    public function run() {
        $mail = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MailMessage::class);
        $mail
            ->from(new Address('no-reply@my-domain.com', 'DEV Server'))
            ->to(new Address('webmaster@my-domain.com', 'Webmaster'))
            ->subject('Slot test')
            ->text('Here is the message')
            ->html('<p>Here is the message</p>')
            ->send();
    }
}

My questions:

Is this way still possible, as in TYPO3 10 the EventDispatcher was
introduced? Yes, it is.
How to debug whether the slot is triggered? I have the strong impression that my slot is not found. (A test with die('test) had no result, same with sending an email.)


Signals/Slots have been dropped in TYPO3 v12. Since then, they have been deprecated but still usable.
Your Slot should normally not be part of a controller but be an own class. A more visual example of Signal/Slot can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/p/brotkrueml/schema/1.11/en-us/Developer/Events.html#id4

@JulianHofmann A changed my class in the sense you mentioned, but still no error messages, debug messages etc.

I updated my answer. Now it should work.

In Powermail 8.4.x the signalslot is still implemented.
From Powermail version 12 onwards, event dispatching must be used.
The SignalSlotDispatcher is marked as deprecated as of TYPO3 11 and will be removed in TYPO3 12.
If you do not use XDebug for debugging you could do a simple die in your sendToApi-method:
die("Is called")
Then you should get a whitescreen with that text.
EDIT:
The reason why your function is not called, is because you use the wrong name for the Signal.
A look in the Powermail FormController shows:
$this->signalDispatch(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__ . 'AfterPersist', [$mail, $hash, $this]);

So the signalname is concatenated from the name of the function and the name of the signal.
So you must implement it like that:
$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher::class);
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    \In2code\Powermail\Controller\FormController::class,
    'optinConfirmActionAfterPersist',
    \MyVendor\MyForms\EventListener\SendToApi::class,
    'run'
);


That is good to know. First question answered.

I had tried with __FUNCTION__. 'AfterPersist' before, without positive result. Now I know better.
